# double-quotes making problems in google

Tags: twig

I used the replace function in `twig` to remove the unwanted pieces of the function and it is working perfectly except it still contains the double-quotes. 
This is the code:

```
{% set htmlheader = sd_htmltitle(false) %}
<title>
   {{ htmlheader|replace({'brand:': "", "websitesub:" : "", "websitecategory:" : "", '"' : ''}) }}
</title>
```

As you can see, I tried replacing the quotation marks, but they still appear in the title. Do you have a solution, or perhaps a better way to handle the situation if applicable? Everything else is getting removed properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `\` before the quotation marks. So try this:

```
   {{ htmlheader|replace({'brand:': "", "websitesub:" : "", "websitecategory:" : "", '\"' : ''}) }}
```

[Here](http://twigfiddle.com/au866q) a working example

Hope this help

Comment: TY Matteo for using your spare time to help fool like me.

Comment: hi @kumbi1 you are welcome! Is a pleasure for me to help other people, don't worry about